# How do I modify the code generation template of the Spring Roo Flex addon?

Tags: apache-flex, spring, spring-roo

I'd like to modify the MVC generated code to use another MVC pattern like Mate or Swiz.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you need to implement your own Roo addon.

Comment: isnt there a template i can modify?

Comment: No, there is no template (as fare as I know). But it should be possible to write your own Mate or Swiz add on, by to copy and modifiy the Roo MVC addon.